# Let $A$ be a totally bounded subset of a complete metric space $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous map.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A$ be a totally bounded subset of a complete metric space $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous map. Then $f|_A:A\to Y$ restriction of $f$ to $A$ is uniform continuous.

My intuition: Since it is totally bounded $\forall \delta>0$ and by finite balls say centered at $$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$$

and inside each ball the $\delta$ is the maximum distance and since $f$ is continuous we can relate our $\delta$ only for $\epsilon$ to prove uniform continuity.

1. I cannot construct to proper way to prove it.
2. Can we do it in more deep way not just using epsilon delta? How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The closure of $A$ is compact  because it is totally bounded and complete. $f$ restricted to the closure is therfore uniformly continuous and hence its restriction to $A$ is also uniformly continuous.

I am using the well known fact that the closure of a totally bouded set is totally bounded. (This is not hard to prove).

Comment: why uniform continuity on closure implies uniform continuity on the set? I see why it is the case for $\mathbb R$ but not for general metric spaces.

Comment: I see, it is trivial.